# Custom UIView within custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview

I want two custom (i.e. subclassed) UIViews in a subclassed UITableViewCell as shown in the below picture.  The two UIViews are the same subclass.

[image]

Both the custom UIViews and the TableViewCell have associated xib's.

I would appreciate some advice on the best way to go about this.  I load the TableViewCell this way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:NULL];
   // CustomCell is an IBOutlet connected to the above nib
   cell = BLCustomCell;
   }
   // configure the cell
}
```

I want to set outlets in the Custom Views to easily display data from my data model.  Do I need a view controller for the Custom Views?  I'm having trouble getting the nib to load for the Custom Views.  (And yes, I realize my code above does not address this issue.)  How do I get it to load?  Does the TableView's controller need outlets to the Custom View objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Well it depends. What kind of information are you going to display on the customViews? Can you give an hint so I can understand you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to handle complex `UITableViewCell`s is to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, with its own `IBOutlet`s that connect to the subviews, then just set properties of your custom cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  There are various other approaches, but this one seems to break down the problem reasonably well, and expands to handle more complex situations.

Take a look at the iOS Recipes book by Matt Drance, it cover this area well.

Comment: Looks like it's time for me to buy Mr. Drance's book.  Thanks!